# jquery sliding side bar Left to right

Tags: jquery, html, sidebar, slidetoggle

I am trying to create a sliding side bar with effects similar to

1. www.wookmark.com
2. http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/slideinmenu.htm.

This is how far I wrote the code.But this is jerky.

1. Can anyone propose a better solution with aniamtions/easing/toggle etc
2. I want code to be independent of left parameter i.e. $("#slide").css("left", "-150px");
   It should be able to slide-in/slide-out with all sorts of div width

Any ideas ?

**CSS**

```
#slide{
border:1.5px solid black;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:150px;
height:100%;
background-color:#F2F2F2;
layer-background-color:#F2F2F2;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slide" style="left: -150px; top: 0px; width: 160px;">
    <p>Something here</p>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slide').mouseover(function() {
            $("#slide").css("left", "0px");
        });

        $('#slide').mouseout(function() {
            $("#slide").css("left", "-150px");
        });

    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method -

```
var width = $('#slide').width() - 10;
$('#slide').hover(function () {
     $(this).stop().animate({left:"0px"},500);     
   },function () {          
     $(this).stop().animate({left: - width  },500);     
});
```

Here I've added `.stop()` before. This will clear animation queue that is built up because of moving mouse quickly.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ztv5K/1/)**

Comment: Thank you @phobos.It works as i wanted.
But if i hover mouse quickly many times on slider div, it goes crazy.
Anyway we can fix that ?