# jQuery: Show sidebar, push off main area

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```js
$(".left-area").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".left-area-content").show();
  $(".left-area-content-preview").hide();
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".left-area-content").hide();
  $(".left-area-content-preview").show();
});


$(".right-area").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".right-area-content").show();
  $(".right-area-content-preview").hide();
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".right-area-content").hide();
  $(".right-area-content-preview").show();
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.left-area {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.left-area-content-preview {
  display: block;
}

.left-area-content {
  display: none;
  width: 500px;
}

.main-area {
  width: 100%;
}

.right-area {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.right-area-content {
  width: 500px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">

  <div class="left-area">
    <div class="left-area-content-preview">
      One
    </div>
    <div class="left-area-content">
      Some cool content
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="main-area">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>

  <div class="right-area">
    <div class="right-area-content-preview">
      Two
    </div>
    <div class="right-area-content">
      Some cool content
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I would need something like this:
http://www.laurelhalo.com/

The main area should keep its width while hovering one of the two sidebars, and push off on one side. There also should be a sliding animation, like in the example.

How is it possible to realize that? Is it possible with jQuery?

Would be very thankful for help. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery sliding side bar Left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745240/jquery-sliding-side-bar-left-to-right)

Comment: Hey, no, unfortunately not. This doesn't push out the main area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `min-width:100%;` to your `main-area` class.

```js
$(".left-area").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".left-area-content").show();
  $(".left-area-content-preview").hide();
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".left-area-content").hide();
  $(".left-area-content-preview").show();
});


$(".right-area").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".right-area-content").show();
  $(".right-area-content-preview").hide();
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".right-area-content").hide();
  $(".right-area-content-preview").show();
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.left-area {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.left-area-content-preview {
  display: block;
}

.left-area-content {
  display: none;
  width: 500px;
}

.main-area {
  width: 100%;
  min-width:100%;
}

.right-area {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.right-area-content {
  width: 500px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">

  <div class="left-area">
    <div class="left-area-content-preview">
      One
    </div>
    <div class="left-area-content">
      Some cool content
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="main-area">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>

  <div class="right-area">
    <div class="right-area-content-preview">
      Two
    </div>
    <div class="right-area-content">
      Some cool content
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Anna_B Np, consider using width to animate menu opening. When you use display block and none(jquery hide and show) you can not animate it with slide effect, if you use width 0-100 on menu you can slide it. Just a tip, as that what your example link is using i think.